# why speech_recognition is no longer working?

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I used the following code a couple of days ago and it was working fine, but now it does not recognize any of the audio files it used to recognize before. I am wondering what is wrong?

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

audio_file_name = 'audio.wav'
audiofile = sr.AudioFile(audio_file_name)
with audiofile as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("i: {}   You said : {}".format(i+1, text))
    except:
        print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")
```

Comment: Check what exception is thrown using print(sys.exc_info()[0],"occured.")

Comment: @abhilb, it puts out: None occured.

Comment: Most likely you exceeded google speech recognition usage limits. You can not process huge audio this way.